# Como puedo activar el auto completado o las sugerencias en Apache Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, web, netbeans, jsp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
*Como puedo activar el auto completado o las sugerencias en Apache Netbeans IDE [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]20 para el código java dentro de <% %>.
En otros proyectos si auto completa hasta en el html del mismo archivo completa pero no completa y da sugerencias en el código de java
*

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Windows, desde el menù ve a `Tools > Options` , después selecciona `Editor` y `Code Completion`, ahì debes seleccionar `Auto Popup Completion Window` para que habilite las sugerencias.
Si usas macOS desde el menù ve a `NetBeans > Preferences…​`, despuès  `Editor` y `Code Completion`

Posiblemente, deshabilitaste las sugerencias, cuando suceda esto puedes llamar las sugerencias usando la secuencia de teclas: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Revisa la documentaciòn (Invoking Code Completion):
[Asistencia de código en NetBeans IDE Java Editor: una guía de referencia](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference/#:%7E:text=When%20the%20Auto%20Popup%20Completion,want%20to%20invoke%20code%20completion.&text=and%20the%20editor%20automatically%20completes,once%20through%20all%20available%20options.)